# Focus an input field with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen this done a few times before I think, but no explicit examples come to mind.

What I want to do is use javascript to toggle the currently selected form field. For example, I have a form field for a date of birth input, and one for an email. Once the date of birth is validated, the cursor will automatically switch to the email input field.

I would be using jQuery's `change()` event binder to monitor field changes and validate locally, and then execute the move on, I'm just not sure how to select a form field.

I may be wrong, and this may not be possible, but if it is, any help would be greatly appreciated as I've yet to find anything using the search queries I think would be most appropriate.

Thanks :).

Comment: Be careful with taking control of navigation, users don't expect it so may find it annoying. The change event occurs after a control loses focus, if you then re-direct focus elsewhere, that will be *really* annoying. If the value doesn't change, then a change event won't be dispatched and you won't redirect, so inconsistent too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger the `focus` event.

```
$("#email").focus();
```

You may find though, that the `change` event doesn't actually fire until the input field has lost focus, so you may need to listen to the `keyup`/`paste` events instead

[Read more about `.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus)

Comment: I'll accept your answer when the timer drops, and props for the right event binder, I just figured that out a few seconds before I read this haha :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the .focus() function. It will set a given element as selected (focused).